# Apply a date pattern a piece os expression

Tags: java, groovy, jasper-reports

I have an expression working inside a Report (jasperReport), the language to work with expressions i groovy. the expression is

```
= Util.textoComun("OCURRENCIA")+ " "+Util.aFecha($F{fecha}).
```

Everything in the same box, but i just want to apply a date pattern at the second part of expression (`Util.aFecha(xx)`), is this possible?

I don't wanna to separate in two boxes.

Util is a java class.

afecha does:

```
public static Date aFecha(String s)
  {
    try
    {
      SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
      formatter.setLenient(false);
      return formatter.parse(s);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Error convertint la data: " + ex);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: what does `Util.aFecha` do?  Convert a Date to a String?

Comment: Is a java class that convert the value to a date, but i can't modify, this is the reason to apply a pattern to the jasper's text box.

Comment: Yeah, but does it convert it to a java Date object, or a java String representation of a Date?

Comment: @ZaoTaoBao `is this possible?` - Yes

Comment: return a Date object, i edit the question. ty.

Comment: Added a possible answer...  You should just be able to call Groovy's `format` method on the returned `Date`

Comment: is this a bad question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so from the edit, it appears that `$F{fecha}` is returning you a String which you parse into a Date with `Util.aFecha`.  In that case (and assuming this is Groovy), you should be able to do:

```
Util.textoComun("OCURRENCIA")+ " "+Util.aFecha($F{fecha}).format( 'EEE, d MMM yyyy' )
```

Comment: WTF!!! this works! ty!i the final expression is:Util.textoComun("OCURRENCIA")+" "+(Util.aFecha($F{fecha}).format("dd-MMM-yy"))